# On the measure of a closed subset of a non-measurable set with infinite outer measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $V\subset [0,1]$ be the Vitali set.
Then for any closed subset $F$ of $V$ we have that $m(F)=0<m^{*}(V)\leq 1$ (where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure and $m^*$ is the Lebesgue outer measure on $\mathbb{R}$).

Let us define $A:=\cup_{n=1}^\infty((2n+1)+V)$, so that we have $m^{*}(A)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty m^{*}(((2n+1)+V))=\sum_{n=1}^\infty m^{*}(V)=\infty$.

Now, if $F$ is any closed subset of $A$, is it true that $m(F)=0$? If the answer is always "yes", how can we proceed to get this result?

Thanks for any hint or comment.

Comment: Define $F_n = [2n+1, 2n+2] \cap F$. Note that $F_n$ is a closed subset of [a translation of] the Vitali set.  Apply additivity of the measure.  Yes?

Comment: $F=\cup_{n=1}^\infty (F\cap[2n+1, 2n+2])$, so that $m(F)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty m(F_n)$=0. Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $F=\bar F\subset A.$ For $n\in \Bbb N$ let $F_n=F\cap [2n+1,2n+2].$

Now $F_n$ is a closed subset of $A\cap [2n+1,2n+2]=V+2n+1$

so $F_n-(2n+1)$ is a closed subset of $(V+2n+1)-(2n+1)=V$

so $0=m(F_n-(2n+1))=m((F_n-(2n+1))+2n+1)=m(F_n).$

And $F=\cup_{n\in \Bbb N}F_n$ so $m(F)\leq \sum_{n\in \Bbb N}m(F_n)=0.$